# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor Pages Web App: What is the reason for the razor pages form data getting erased even after using Ajax call?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, razor-pages

I am building a web application using the ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC and Razor pages.

I am new to Razor pages.

I created a basic application using above. I created a registeration form having following three fields -

1. User name
2. User email address
3. Verification code

There are two buttons  -

1. Send Code
2. Register

I am providing a feature in which the user can verify its email address before clicking on the "Register" button.
A verification code will be sent to the user to the email address, when user clicks on the "Send Code" button.
The user should then enter the code in the "Verification code" field and submit the form by clicking on the "Register" button.

**Issue**
When user clicks on the "Send Code" button, the code is send but the ***form data gets cleared i.e.  "User name" and "User email address" fields values get erased***. I used Ajax to call the "Send verification code" function. Following is the code -

**Index.cshtml**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">

    <div class="form-row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Credentials</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="user.UserName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" asp-for="user.UserName" class="form-control" id="UserName"
                   name="UserName" placeholder="Enter Full Name"
                   value="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="user.UserEmailAddress" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" asp-for="user.UserEmailAddress" class="form-control" 
                    value=""
                   name="UserEmailAddress" placeholder="Enter Email Address" id="UserEmailAddress">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <button id="btn1"
                        class="btn btn-primary mb-sm-1">
                    @Model.EmailVerifCodeLabel
                </button>
                <div id="grid" class="col">
                    <input type="text" asp-for="user.EmailVerifCode"
                           class="form-control" id="Emailverifcode" placeholder="Enter code">
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btn1").click(function () {
            var UserName = $("#UserName").val();
            var UserEmailAddress = $("#UserEmailAddress").val();
            alert(UserName);
            alert(UserEmailAddress);
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Page("/Register")?handler=SendEmailVerificationCode",
            method: "GET",
            data: { UserName: UserName, UserEmailAddress: UserEmailAddress }
        })
    });
    </script>
}
```

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```
       public JsonResult  OnGetSendEmailVerificationCode(string UserName, string UserEmailAddress)
        {
                Random generator = new Random();
                String verifCode = generator.Next(0, 999999).ToString("D6");
_configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("DefaultConnection").Value;
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("verifCode", verifCode);
                _myemailSender = new EmailSender();
                var emailresult = _myemailSender.SendEmailAsync(UserName, UserEmailAddress, verifCode, _configuration);
         
            return null;
        }
```

Question: What is the reason for the razor pages form data getting erased even after using Ajax call?

Comment: You are using way too much mark-up for form inputs. Please start with one of the tutorial apps for Razor pages apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When user clicks on the "Send Code" button, the code is send but the form data gets cleared i.e. "User name" and "User email address" fields values get erased.

```
<button id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary mb-sm-1"> Model.EmailVerifCodeLabel</button>
```

You do not specify the `type` attribute for above `<button>` tag within your `<form>`, it would work as a submit button, which cause form submit and user inputs cleared.

To fix it, you can try to explicitly specify `type="button"` for `btn1` button.

```
<button id="btn1" type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary mb-sm-1">
    @Model.EmailVerifCodeLabel
</button>
```

Or call `preventDefault()` method to prevent it from submitting a form.

```
$("#btn1").click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var UserName = $("#UserName").val();
    //...
```